# Incorrect Jquery file reference working - how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a query, i am using jquery in one of my aspx file using below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl
("js/jquery-1.8.1.js")% >"> </script>
```

However in my js folder i have kept jquery-1.8.2.min file, still code for cascading drop down is working.

How its possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that `js/jquery-1.8.1.js` doesn't exist in theory in your js folder?

Comment: Yes correct,js/jquery-1.8.1.js doesnt exist in folder still cascading drop downs which i have inmplemented using jquery are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might have 8.1 in the same folder as well
2. It might just be cached. As soon as you clear your cache memory, it will go away. Use another browser to test this option.
3. You might use a master page that has the other version linked..

Comment: Its not cached as i have tried it after clearing cache moreover when i remove jquery-1.8.2.min from folder it stops working..its strange for me. i am not using any master page. Also i do not have 8.1 in same folder.